# FreeRTOS software timer (taskSCHEDULER_RUNNING) fault

Tags: timer, freertos, nxp-microcontroller

Hardware:
NXP M4 MKE14

Software:
MCUXpresso 10.1.1

Implementation of one software timer goes very well. When starting a second timer the microcontroller doesn't respond anymore. I get the error back "taskSCHEDULER_RUNNING". But if this not runs the system doesn't do anything.

I implemented the timers and one task like this:

```
   /* Create the queue used by the queue send and queue receive tasks. */
        xQueue = xQueueCreate(/* The number of items the queue can hold. */
                              mainQUEUE_LENGTH,
                              /* The size of each item the queue holds. */
                              sizeof(uint32_t));

xSensorTimer = xTimerCreate(/* A text name, purely to help
                                   debugging. */
                                     "SensorTimer",
                                     /* The timer period, in this case
                                     1000ms (1s). */
                                     SENSOR_TIMER_PERIOD_MS,
                                     /* This is a periodic timer, so
                                     xAutoReload is set to pdTRUE. */
                                     pdTRUE,
                                     /* The ID is not used, so can be set
                                     to anything. */
                                     (void *)0,
                                     /* The callback function */
                                     vTimerCallback_SensorTimer);
                                if(xSensorTimer==NULL) {
                                    for(;;); /*failure! */
                                }

xSUS_BUS_TIMEOUT_Timer = xTimerCreate(/* A text name, purely to help
                                   debugging. */
                                     "SUS_BUS_TIMEOUT_Timer",
                                     /* The timer period, in this case
                                     1000ms (1s). */
                                     SUS_BUS_TIMEOUT_PERIOD_MS,
                                     /* This is a periodic timer, so
                                     xAutoReload is set to pdTRUE. */
                                     pdFALSE,
                                     /* The ID is not used, so can be set
                                     to anything. */
                                     (void *)1,
                                     /* The callback function */
                                     vTimerCallback_SUSBUSTIMEOUT);
                                if(xSUS_BUS_TIMEOUT_Timer==NULL) {
                                    for(;;); /*failure! */
                                }

    xTaskCreate(/* The function that implements the task. */
                prvQueueModuleTask,
                /* Text name for the task, just to help debugging. */
                "Module",
                /* The size (in words) of the stack that should be created
                for the task. */
                configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE + 166,
                /* A parameter that can be passed into the task.  Not used
                in this simple demo. */
                NULL,
                /* The priority to assign to the task.  tskIDLE_PRIORITY
                (which is 0) is the lowest priority.  configMAX_PRIORITIES - 1
                is the highest priority. */
                mainQUEUE_MODULE_TASK_PRIORITY,
                /* Used to obtain a handle to the created task.  Not used in
                this simple demo, so set to NULL. */
                NULL);

    /* Start the tasks and timers running. */
    vTaskStartScheduler();

    /* The program should never enter this while loop */
    while(1)
    {
        ;
    }
}

static void vTimerCallback_SensorTimer (xTimerHandle pxTimer)
{
    ReadTemperature();
    ADCMeasurement();
}

static void vTimerCallback_SUSBUSTIMEOUT (xTimerHandle pxTimer)
{
   //Reset the communication state back to the header state
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "got the error taskSCHEDULER_RUNNING back". When and how did you get that error?

With regards to the creating of timers; have you allocated enough heap for FreeRTOS (in your FreeRTOSConfig.h)?

Comment: I got this error back from the function when starting the second timer with:  if(xSUS_BUS_TIMEOUT_Timer==NULL) {
                                    for(;;); /*failure! */
I followed this tutorial:
https://mcuoneclipse.com/2018/05/27/tutorial-understanding-and-using-freertos-software-timers/
Heap size is 10240. If you mean this #define configTOTAL_HEAP_SIZE                   ((size_t)(10240)) 
configAPPLICATION_ALLOCATED_HEAP   is 0.

Comment: Are you able to have a look at the `xFreeBytesRemaining` variable? It is a FreeRTOS variable which shows how many bytes are remaining in the heap. The size of a timer is approx. 48 bytes.